# How to make fixed element stop scroll on bottom of relative parent?

Tags: css, scroll, parent

I have this simple example:

```css
#main {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
}

#fixed {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="fixed"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make fixed stop scrolling with top when it has reached the bottom of `#wrap`? (If possible without JavaScript)

Right now it keeps positioning in the top of the screen.

Example in:
http://jsfiddle.net/fo2pogku/1

Comment: Fixed does not scroll, because.. well .. it is fixed. I do not understand, what your problem is.

Comment: My problem is, that although the parent div is already out of sight, the fixed div is still visible. I'd like it to stay inside the relative div and get out of sight as soon as the relative div gets out of sight

Comment: Sounds like a case for `position:sticky`...but that's Chrome only I think at the moment.

Comment: The JSFiddle you provided has no parent or child element, only siblings.

Comment: is there a javascript solution? Pauli?

Comment: Thank you. Your fiddle is not showing the problem, you should update it with the example code above.

Comment: Sorry my bad Thomas, i mis-copied the jsfiddle, it's updated now

Answer (score 2):

you need jquery. I'm afraid you can't do that with just css.

you can add this css:

```
.relative {
    position:relative;
}
```

and add that class to "fixed" when scroll at wrap height (200px) with:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $(".fixed").addClass("relative");
            } else {
                $(".fixed").removeClass("relative");
            }

        });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HFjU6/3217/)**

Comment: I'd recommend not to use hard coded values when avoidable.

Comment: A simple way to avoid the hardcoded values in Alvaro's exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/HFjU6/3222/ basically it's the same, just checking the position of some invisible anchor at the end of the <div>

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without JS. A possible solution is to bind an event on the scroll of the page.

As soon as the page is scroll to the bottom of `#wrap` the `#fixed` div becomes an absolute position (instead of fixed)

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    var wrapBottom = $('#wrap').position().top+$('#wrap').outerHeight(true),
        scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if( scrollPos > wrapBottom ) {
        $('#fixed').css( {'position':'absolute','top':wrapBottom+'px'});
    }
    else {
        $('#fixed').css( {'position':'fixed','top':'0px'});        
    } 
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HFjU6/3218/)

Answer (score 1):

Smoothly scrolling with the parent when its about time:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
    var fixed = $('#fixed');
    
    // Class identifier for scrolling with the parent
    var scrollClass = 'not-so-fixed';
    
    // get bottom position of #wrap
    var posBottom = fixed.parent().position().top + fixed.parent().outerHeight()- fixed.outerHeight();
    
    // Check scroll position
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > posBottom)
       fixed.addClass(scrollClass);
    else
      fixed.removeClass(scrollClass);
});
```

```css
body, html {margin: 0}
#main {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:2000px;
    background-color:#000;
}


#wrap {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#f00;
    position: relative;
}

#fixed {
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

#fixed.not-so-fixed {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="fixed"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend not to use `!mportant` ... ever :)

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez touché :) Did it because he uses ids, not classes. I'll edit the example.